# How do I cross the large gap with the crusher in Florennum's East Guard Tower?

Tags: swordigo

In Florennum, there's a dungeon called "East Guard Tower" that leads to the area's second treasure. I can cross most of the jumping and crusher obstacles easily, but then I reach a large gap with a huge crusher:

[image: Larger crusher in Florennum's East Guard Tower]

I've tried dozens of times to time my double jump correctly, but no matter what, I'm too slow and die instantly when the crusher comes down.

How can I traverse this gap? Everyone says to double tap the forward button but it doesn't work. The crusher is too fast.Can anyone please make a video showing how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use double-run, a somewhat hidden move that, as far as I've seen, is only required for this puzzle. If you double-tap the forward button, you'll be able to run faster than you normally can, which will also translate to your jump. Besides the slight increase in speed, you'll know if you are double-running if the trail of smoke that you normally see when you start running doesn't go away.

Without this, the jump is impossible: no amount of timing or precision will give you enough forward momentum to beat the crusher.

So when the crusher is coming back up, double-tap the forward button and jump just as the crusher passes the platform you're on. It may take one or two tries to pull it off, but you'll be able to make the jump without a whole lot of effort or precision.

Answer (score 0):

Just come running speed by double tap on run button and then press once long on jump then press again so tat you can reach next